# Running Kafka on Windows

Tags: windows, apache-kafka

Have a question in installing Kafka on windows. Our server farm is totally windows based. I have a C++ application and an asp.net mvc application that need to exchange huge volume of fast data. We are contemplating on using Kafka for the data passing layer. We are not sure if Kafka is recommended to run on windows. Any feedback will be much appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I've never heard anyone even thinking about running Kafka on Windows servers.
I assume you have some type of hypervisor? If that's true, why don't you spin up 3 Linux VMs and run Kafka cluster there.

If you're running on bare metal, you could use Docker, which I think runs "natively" on Windows now (a hack with some sort of hypervisor, same as on OSX).  With docker, you'll want to mount volumes from your host to avoid losing data if a container crashes.

We run Kafka on Ubuntu servers and it has been a smooth ride.

Answer (score 1):

While generally recommended would be to have Linux system for Kafka,

Kafaka (as of 0.10) does support Windows, take a look at http://kafka.apache.org/documentation.html#quickstart

and search web for older posts like http://blog.anilot.tk/2014/08/06/Set-Up-Kafka-On-Windows/